# RxJs getValue for nested BehaviorSubject object

Tags: nested, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I'm working with angular 4 and RxJS 5, I have an object with the following structure (with nested subjects, in this example only 2 levels):

```
objs = BehaviorSubject<MyObj[]>;

MyObj = {
    prop1: BehaviorSubject<string> = "prop1";
    prop2: BehaviorSubject<string> = "prop2";

    prop1.subscribe(newValue => prop2 = prop1);
}
```

So if I try to output the value of objs I got something like the following:

```
console.log(objs.value) =>
    [
    {
        prop1: BehaviorSubject<string>;
        prop2: BehaviorSubject<string>;
        },
    {
        ...
    }]
```

so the result doesn't include the values of prop1 and prop2 but I still have BehaviorSubject at the second level.

Is there a way to get the nested objs value like the following?:

```
objs = [{
    prop1: "prop1";
    prop2: "prop2"
 }, {...}]
```

I'm wondering if there's a sort of the knockout ko.toJSON (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Do you think it is generally a bad practice to have nested BehaviorSubjects or people do it everyday :)?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing builtin that does that.  You could certainly roll your own method.  This might be something you can start with:

```
function isPrimitive(obj: any) {
  return obj !== Object(obj);
}

function desubjectify(obj: any) {

  if(isPrimitive(obj)) {
    return obj;
  }

  if(obj instanceof BehaviorSubject) {
    return desubjectify(obj.value);
  }

  let transformed: any = {};
  for(let key of Object.keys(obj).filter(key => !key.startsWith('_'))) {
    let value = obj[key];
    if(value instanceof BehaviorSubject) {
      transformed[key] = desubjectify(value.value);
    } else {
      transformed[key] = desubjectify(value);
    }
  }
  return transformed;
}
```

Nested behavior subjects seems fishy to me but I wouldn't rule it out immediately with out knowing more details.  However, I would recommend you find a good tutorial on `ngrx/store` and read it.  Anytime people start to work a lot with behavior subjects I would recommend this.

Comment: Why ngrx would solve my issue? I've tried out ng Redux and ngrx but I don't use it since my state is too complex/nested and the effort of writing the actions + reducers + complex payload is too much.

Comment: Again, I don't understand your true problem (e.g. I don't know why your state is nested in such a way) but ngrx was designed for handling complex state.  So anytime I see someone trying to do too much with observables or subjects I figure it's worth a look.  If you've looked and it doesn't apply then you can ignore my advice.  It was more intended in case you hadn't heard of those technologies.